# Trouble using the and operator within IF statement

Tags: javascript

I believe the issue stems from the && operator as I get a result when I switch it to ||. If I keep it && a result doesn't return.

My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="greeting"></p></center>

<script>
var time = new Date().getHours();
let phrase = "";

if ((time > 6) && (time < 12)) {
    phrase = "Good Morning";
} else if ((time > 12) && (time < 18)) {
    phrase = "Good Afternoon";
} else if ((time >= 18) && (time <= 6)) {
    phrase = "Good Evening";
}
document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = phrase;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is `&&` the culprit? It's evident it's your conditions...

Comment: How can something be greater than 18 but less than 6? It is not possible.

Comment: Yeah definitely overlooked that, was thinking about it in a weird way. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your final `if` statement will never evaluate to `true`; `time` cannot be greater than (or equal to) `18` at the same time that it is less than (or equal to) `6`. You're looking for an `OR` statement (`||`) here, as the `time` will always be either after 6pm (`> 18`) or before 6am (`< 6`) -- it cannot be both:

```
else if ((time >= 18) || (time <= 6))
```

Having said that, this correction would now cover **all** possible hours, meaning that the final condition is actually irrelevant; if either of the first two `if` statements are not stepped in to, the above conditional will **always** be met. As such, you can simply replace it with `else`:

```js
var time = new Date().getHours();
let phrase = "";

if ((time > 6) && (time < 12)) {
  phrase = "Good Morning";
} else if ((time > 12) && (time < 18)) {
  phrase = "Good Afternoon";
} else {
  phrase = "Good Evening";
}

document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = phrase;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <center>
    <h2>Individual Tech Proficiency 1</h2>
    <h4>Emulator</h4>
    <p id="greeting"></p>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Should just remove the last `else if` statement and turn it to a `else`, no sense if having a check for remaining hours

Comment: Actually, considering this final `if` conditional now covers all possible scenarios, that's a good point. I've just updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: I appreciate the help, thank you. So my goal is to find the window of time 6-12, 12-6pm, 6pm to 6am. Is there a better method of doing this? I tried looking up a between operator with a range but couldn't really find out. I know how I would approach it in Python but not JS.

Comment: No probs! You could use [**`.includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) if you want the same logic to apply in each case, but considering you want *different* logic to apply to each of the three states, three separate `if` conditionals is probably your best bet.